# Reshape and rearrange array

Tags: arrays, matlab, reshape

I have a large array, which looks like this:

```
1
4
5
3
6
2
7
4
3
```

I want to rearrange this array that it looks like this:

```
7 4 3
3 6 2
1 4 5
```

My original array has the size 13700x1, so I cannot do it manually and if I use the reshape function, the array gets shaped in the wrong way:

```
1 3 7
4 6 4
5 2 3
```

I hope my intention is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [1,4,5,3,6,2,7,4,3]';
A = flipud(reshape(x,3,3)');
```

Comment: In case you are not aware, and for OP: `.'` is transpose, not `'`. However, it conveniently works for matrices with only real numbers. It's good practice to always use `.'` to avoid bad habits. But nice answer =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin no I did not know that! So what is `'`, complex conjugate?

Comment: Note: This assumes the vector has a square number of elements, which is doesn't. Thus it will fail for OP's dataset.

Comment: You mean the 13400x1 vector? I was kind of assuming that the square result of the MWE was just an arbitrary shape, and he knows what shape he wants to reshape his vector into.

Comment: That may be the case, and if that's the case then you are right (you and alex had my upvote a few hours ago =) ). Tips: `reshape(x,3,[])`. You can leave one dimension undefined. This way the code will work even if the number of elements change (assuming it's still a multiple of 3). It's a bit easier than: `reshape(x,3,numel(x)/3)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
tmpArray = [1
4
5
3
6
2
7
4
3]

flipud(reshape(tmpArray, 3, 3).')
```

Comment: Note: This assumes the vector has a square number of elements, which is doesn't. Thus it will fail for OP's dataset.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers assume your vector contains a square number of elements, `4, 9, 16 ...`. This is true for the example vector, but not for the one you're actually working with (it's 13700x1 according to the question).

This means that the `flipud(reshape())` approach will give an error:

> Product of known dimensions, 3, not divisible into total number of
>   elements, 13924.

This is not a problem if you don't want a square matrix, as numbers that can be represented as a product of any of the numbers: `2, 5, 137`.

If you want a square matrix, you need to pad the vector with zeros, NaNs or something else. This can be done the following way:

```
A = randi(100,13700,1);        %% Random 13700x1 matrix
n = numel(A);                  %% Number of elements in A (13700 in this case)
elements = ceil(sqrt(n))^2;    %% Number of elements needed in order to make a square matrix
B = [A; zeros(elements-n,1)];  %% Pad the vectors with zeros.
                               %% You can also d0 B = [A; nan(elements-n,1)];
final_matrix = flipud(reshape(B, sqrt(elements),[]).');  %% Final operation
```